# What features of xgboost are affected by seed (random_state)?

Tags: python, numpy, xgboost, random-seed

The [Python API](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html) doesn't give much more information other than that the `seed=` parameter is passed to `numpy.random.seed`:

> **seed** (*int*) – Seed used to generate the folds (passed to numpy.random.seed).

But what features of `xgboost` use `numpy.random.seed`?

- Running `xgboost` with all default settings still produces the same performance even when altering the seed.
- I have already been able to verify `colsample_bytree` does so; different seeds yield different performance.
- I have been told it is also used by `subsample` and the other `colsample_*` features, which seems plausible since any form of sampling requires randomness.

What other features of `xgboost` rely on `numpy.random.seed`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Boosted trees are grown sequentially, with tree growth within one iteration being distributed among threads. To avoid overfitting, randomness is induced through the following params:

- `colsample_bytree`
- `colsample_bylevel`
- `colsample_bynode`
- `subsample` (note the `*sample*` pattern)
- `shuffle` in CV folder creation for cross validation

In addition, you may encounter non-determinism, not controlled by random state, in the following places:

> [GPU] histogram building is not deterministic due to the nonassociative aspect of floating point summation.

> Using gblinear booster with shotgun updater is nondeterministic as it uses Hogwild algorithm

> when using GPU ranking objective, the result is not deterministic due to the non-associative aspect of floating point summation.

**Comment Re: *how* you know this?**

For this to know it's helpful:

1. To be aware of how trees are grown: [Demystify Modern Gradient Boosting Trees](https://everdark.github.io/k9/notebooks/ml/gradient_boosting/gbt.nb.html) (references may be also helpful)
2. Scanning documentation [full text](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/xgboost/latest/xgboost.pdf) for the terms of interest: `random`, `sample`, `deterministic`, `determinism` etc.
3. Lastly (firstly?), knowing why you need sampling and similar cases from counterparts like bagged trees ([RANDOM FORESTS](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Ebreiman/randomforest2001.pdf) by Leo Breiman) and neural networks ([Deep learning with Python](http://faculty.neu.edu.cn/yury/AAI/Textbook/Deep%20Learning%20with%20Python.pdf) by François Chollet, chapter on overfitting) may also be helpful.

Comment: Thank you! Can you maybe share *how* you know this?

Comment: @jorijnsmit Please see `Re:` in the answer text.

Comment: if i keep random_state the same should i in theory get exact same results?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want the exhaustive list, you could look at the source at GitHub. Searching with keywords on github gives good insignt.

[search for 'rand'](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/search?q=rand) - 15 results

[search for 'seed' and python filter](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/search?l=Python&q=seed) - 20 results

Comment: This is a start. Problem is that the Python code is just a wrapper around the core which is written in C++ by the looks of it. Doing it this way would require vast knowledge of the source code. I was hoping for a less elaborate solution.

Comment: I have not used this library but typically the library functions that use randomness will have some arguments to control the behaviour. If the function you are using doesn't have any such arguments listen then I think it is safe to assume it doesn't use randomness. You can test this by quickly calling your functions with the same output multiple times and see if it returns the same output.